# Расчёт границ доверительного интервала для линии регрессии на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, выборка

Подскажите как рассчитать границы доверительного интервала для линии регрессии.
Много примеров видал, но каждый по разному реализован, поэтому не понял как провести расчёты.

Файл: [dataset.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5fqh/3jmqPTc8H)

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm

df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", sep = ";", header = None)
x = df[0].astype("float").values.tolist()
y = df[1].astype("float").values.tolist()
print("Мощность двигателя (x): \n", x, "\n\nВремя разгона (y): \n", y)
df.shape

# Среднее выборочное значение переменных x и y
x_srednee = np.mean(x)
y_srednee = np.mean(y)
print("Выборочное среднее значение переменной x: ", x_srednee, "\nВыборочное среднее значение переменной y: ", y_srednee)

# Среднее квадратическое отколнение переменных x и y
Sx = np.std(x)
Sy = np.std(y)
print("\nСреднее квадратическое отколнение переменной x: ", Sx, "\nСреднее квадратическое отколнение переменной y: ", Sy)

# Расчёт: - Коэффициента корреляции;
#         - Оценок параметров парвной линейно регерссии
#         - Характеристик оценки регрессии
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
print("Коэффициент корреляции: ", r_value, # r_value - Коэффициент корреляции - Rxy
      "\n\nКоэффициент регрессии: ", slope, # slope - Коэффициент регрессии - b
      "\nСвободный член регрессии: ", intercept, # intercept - Свободный член регрессии - a
      "\n\nСтандартная ошибка регрессии: ", std_err, # std_err - Стандартная ошибка регрессии - Se
      "\nКоэффициент детерминации: ", r_value**2) # R-squared - Коэффициент детерминации - R^2

# Ввод доверительной вероятности
dov_ver = float(input("Введите доверительную вероятность: "))

# Критическое значение доверительной вероятности
values_dov_ver = norm.ppf(dov_ver)
print("Критическое значение: ", values_dov_ver)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не понимаю, как могут быть ПО РАЗНОМУ реализованы (конечно, не с точностью до названий пеерменных, а в принципе) скрипты, считающие по одной и той-же формуле. Может вы имеете ввиду, что есть доверительные интервалы для коэффициентов регрессии и доверительные интервалы для значений регресси в точке? Тогда да, это действительно разные (хотя и похожие) методы. Могут быть реализации разными инструментами с использованием numpy, pandas, scipy, sklearn или "чистого python", но в основе всегда лежит одни и те-же алгоритмы.

Хотите разобраться в теме - сначала разберитесь в теории. Ну например вот тут

http://sun.tsu.ru/mminfo/2016/Dombrovski/book/chapter-2/chapter-2-4.htm

а потом запрограммировать соответствующую формулу - дело техники (и вашего владения Python).